# How to insert data from two tables into one table

Tags: sql

I need to insert values from two tables into one table. Eg Table 1 is outward and table 2 is product table. I need to insert values into outward table and from product table i have productname which needs to be inserted into outward table.  My code is

```
INSERT INTO tbltrn_outward, tbltrn product(chalanno,godownsrno, igodownsrno,deladdress,outwarddate,productname,qty,boxes,rate,price,batchcombo,active,createdby,createdon,fyearsno) 
VALUES('$chalanno','$godownsrno','$igodownsrno','$deladdress','$outwarddate','$productname','$qty','$boxes','$rate','$price','$batchcombo','$active','$createdby','$createdon','$fyearsrno')";
```

Comment: What is the table structure of the 3rd table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the basic:

```
INSERT INTO tbltrn_outward(chalanno, godownsrno, ... )
SELECT
   column1
   , column2
   , ...
FROM tbltrn_product
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `insert into .. select from` construct for this purpose like

```
INSERT INTO tbltrn_outward(col1,col2,col3, ...)
select col1,col2,col3,...
from  tbltrn_product
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax mentioned in question is not correct.

Below Query would help if fields in table1, table2 are unique and table3 contains all fields of table1 and 2:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (SELECT * FROM TABLE1,TABLE2);
```

Refer fiddle here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3cc4/1

Below query would help if fields overlap in table1 and 2:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (SELECT TABLE2.FIELD1, TABLE1.FIELD2,
                TABLE2.FIELD3, TABLE2.FIELD4
                FROM TABLE1,TABLE2);
```

Refer fiddle here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/479f4/1